# Pri Yitzchak for sale?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, biography

Does anyone know if they reprinted the sefer Pri Yitzchak by Rav Yitzchak Blazer / Peterburger?
Here is a video biography: https://outorah.org/p/78974/.

Do any stores sell it?
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: http://www.publishyoursefer.com/reprints/t/9257

Comment: https://kolsefer.com/shop/libros-en-hebreo/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7-%D7%91%D7%9B-envio-gratis-2-semanas/

Comment: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/1115